# Looping over jquery tic tact toe functions

Tags: jquery, loops, refactoring

Is there a way I can create a loop function in this code to reduce the redundancy of having to write it out. I just need to learn how to refactor.

How would you suggest I start to refactor this code? Where can I use a loop with a formula to pass through the functions instead of using the if statements?

```
    var human = 'x'; 
    var computer = 'o'; 
    var compMove;
    var turn = 0; 

    var boardCheck; 
    var a1; 
    var a2;
    var a3;
    var b1;
    var b2;
    var b3;
    var c1;
    var c2;
    var c3;

    var checkWin; 
    var xWin = false; 
    var oWin = false; 
    var winAlert; 

    var newGame;
    var clearBoard;



    var newGame = function () {
        $('td').one('click', function (event) {
            if (turn == 0) {
                $(this).text(human);
                boardCheck();
                checkWin();
                turn == 1;
                compMove();
                boardCheck();
                checkWin();
            }
        });
    };



    $(document).ready(function () {
        newGame();
    });

//need to refactor
    var compMove = function () {
        if (a1 == "" && ((a3 == "x" && a2 == "x") || (c3 == "x" && b2 == "x") || (c1 == "x" && b1 == "x"))) {
            $('#a1').text("o");
            turn = 0;
        } else {
          if (a2 == "" && ((a1 == "x" && a3 == "x") || (c2 == "x" && b2 == "x"))) {
            $('#a2').text("o");
            turn = 0;
            }
            else{
            if (a3 == "" && ((a1 == "x" && a2 == "x") || (c1 == "x" && b2 == "x") || (c3 == "x" && b3 == "x"))) {
                $('#a3').text("o");
                turn = 0;
            }
                else{
                if (c3 == "" && ((c1 == "x" && c2 == "x") || (a1 == "x" && b2 == "x") || (a3 == "x" && b3 == "x"))) {
                    $('#c3').text("o");
                    turn = 0;
            }
                    else{
                    if (c1 == "" && ((c3 == "x" && c2 == "x") || (a3 == "x" && b2 == "x") || (a1 == "x" && b1 == "x"))) {
                        $('#c1').text("o");
                        turn = 0;
            }
                        else{
                        if (c2 == "" && ((c3 == "x" && c1 == "x") || (a2 == "x" && b2 == "x"))) {
                            $('#c2').text("o");
                            turn = 0;
            }
                            else{
                            if (b1 == "" && ((b3 == "x" && b2 == "x") || (a1 == "x" && c1 == "x"))) {
                                $('#b1').text("o");
                                turn = 0;
            }
                                else{
                                if (b3 == "" && ((a3 == "x" && c3 == "x") || (b2 == "x" && b1 == "x"))) {
                                    $('#b3').text("o");
                                    turn = 0;
            }
                                    else{
                                    if (b2 == "" && ((a3 == "x" && c1 == "x") || (c3 == "x" && a1 == "x") || (b3 == "x" && b1 == "x") || (c2 == "x" && a2 == "x"))) {
                                        $('#b2').text("o");
                                        turn = 0;
            }
                                       else{ 
                                        if (b2 == "") {
                                            $('#b2').text("o");
                                            turn = 0;

                                        }
                                            else{
                                            if (a1 == "") {
                                                $('#a1').text("o");
                                                turn = 0;

                                        }
                                                else{
                                                if (c3 == "") {
                                                $('#c3').text("o");
                                                turn = 0;

                                        } 
                                                    else {
                                                    if (c2 == "") {
                                                $('#c2').text("o");
                                                turn = 0;

                                        }
                                                        else{
                                                        if (b1 == "") {
                                                $('#b1').text("o");
                                                turn = 0;

                                        }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }


                                            }
                                       }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }   
    };



    boardCheck = function () {
        a1 = $('#a1').html();
        a2 = $('#a2').html();
        a3 = $('#a3').html();
        b1 = $('#b1').html();
        b2 = $('#b2').html();
        b3 = $('#b3').html();
        c1 = $('#c1').html();
        c2 = $('#c2').html();
        c3 = $('#c3').html();
    };


    checkWin = function () { 
        if ((a1 == a2 && a1 == a3 && (a1 == "x")) || 
        (b1 == b2 && b1 == b3 && (b1 == "x")) || 
        (c1 == c2 && c1 == c3 && (c1 == "x")) || 
        (a1 == b1 && a1 == c1 && (a1 == "x")) || 
        (a2 == b2 && a2 == c2 && (a2 == "x")) || 
        (a3 == b3 && a3 == c3 && (a3 == "x")) || 
        (a1 == b2 && a1 == c3 && (a1 == "x")) || 
        (a3 == b2 && a3 == c1 && (a3 == "x")) 
        ) {
            xWin = true;
            winAlert();

        } else { 
            if ((a1 == a2 && a1 == a3 && (a1 == "o")) || 
            (b1 == b2 && b1 == b3 && (b1 == "o")) || 
            (c1 == c2 && c1 == c3 && (c1 == "o")) || 
            (a1 == b1 && a1 == c1 && (a1 == "o")) || 
            (a2 == b2 && a2 == c2 && (a2 == "o")) || 
            (a3 == b3 && a3 == c3 && (a3 == "o")) || 
            (a1 == b2 && a1 == c3 && (a1 == "o")) || 
            (a3 == b2 && a3 == c1 && (a3 == "o")) 
            ) {
                oWin = true;
                winAlert();

            } else { 
                if (((a1 == "x") || (a1 == "o")) && ((b1 == "x") || (b1 == "o")) && ((c1 == "x") || (c1 == "o")) && ((a2 == "x") || (a2 == "o")) && ((b2 == "x") || (b2 == "o")) && ((c2 == "x") || (c2 == "o")) && ((a3 == "x") || (a3 == "o")) && ((b3 == "x") || (b3 == "o")) && ((c3 == "x") || (c3 == "o"))) {
                    alert("It's a tie!");
                }
            }
        }
    };


    var winAlert = function () {
        if (xWin == true) {
            alert("You won!");
            clearBoard(); 
        } else {
            if (oWin == true) {
                alert("Sorry, you lose!");
                clearBoard(); 
            }
        }
    };



    var clearBoard = $('#restart').click(function (event) {
        a1 = $('#a1').text("");
        b1 = $('#b1').text("");
        c1 = $('#c1').text("");
        a2 = $('#a2').text("");
        b2 = $('#b2').text("");
        c2 = $('#c2').text("");
        a3 = $('#a3').text("");
        b3 = $('#b3').text("");
        c3 = $('#c3').text("");
        xWin = false;
        oWin = false;
        newGame();
        location.reload(); 
    });
```

I am looking to emulate this loop

```
function isWinner(board){
  for(var i=0; i<this.wins.length; i++){
    var a, b, c;
    //these varaibles become what the board is holding 'x', 'o', or 0
    a = board[wins[i][0]];
    b = board[wins[i][1]];
    c = board[wins[i][2]];

    if(a == b && a == c && a != 0){
      return a;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: it seems like your asking for a code review, see [codereview.stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I guess that writing code from the original idea (or game play rule) may be even easier to read your code and try to refactor it. I've never done such complicated nested IF-statements. Once I need to do so in the first thought, I would try doing it another way. You can always increase the complexity of your ***data structure*** to increase the simplicity of your ***algorithm***. It would be easier to follow and manage.